# Link to "edit the above snippet" impossibly tiny in IE11

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, internet-explorer

Well, today I was looking at a question and testing some code.

It is an experimental code I'm playing around to use in stack snippets.

And I've noticed this:

[image: stacksnippet]

You see that VERY tiny text?
Well, I never saw it!

I had no idea that there was a feature to edit stack snippets! Until today!
Why is that? How come I never saw it?
The answer is **very** simple: The text is too small.

But the solution is pretty easy.
Add this to your `all.css`:

```
.edit-snippet{font-size:15px}
```

This is happening on me on IE11, running on Windows 8.1.
Since this is something very easy to fix, and quick, I won't get into all the details about my system.

---

Similarly to IE11, this also happens on Google Chrome, but the text size is 12px (which is easily readable) but it is 8.25px on IE11 (impossibly tiny).